Scheduled path of my flow runs immediately
I have a flow that is triggered when updating a custom object, and inside this flow is a scheduled route. I have configured two conditions:
First, 24 hours after the approvalSubmissionDate field is updated, the following conditions are checked:

If stage is equal to “Pending”.
If approvalSubmissionDate is not null.

If both conditions are true, an email is triggered and, in addition, the submissionDate field is updated so that the comparison is performed again. This process stops until the state of the object changes from “Pending” to another value.
This flow works correctly in my sandbox environment, but when I test in the QA instance, the scheduled path is not respected and the flow is executed immediately. In sandbox, I experienced a similar problem, but I solved it by defining the Default Workflow User in the Process Automation Settings. I did the same in QA, but the problem persists.
Could someone help me understand what could be happening and how to fix it?
Entry criteria for the Flow

Scheduled path

Decision for the reminder

Scheduled path settins

Process Automation Settings


What are the entry criteria for the Flow itself?  Please [edit] your post to include those details.

@DavidCheng flow has no input conditions, it is executed when the record is updated

Since your flow has no entry conditions, it runs every time a record is updated, regardless of what field is changed.
Then your scheduled path is executed, and it acts on any record with Stage = Pending and approval submissions date = any date.  This happens even if you didn't change the date.
You need to set entry conditions on the Flow so it runs only when the date IsChanged and the stage = Pending.  Then you don't need the Decision element because you already have the correct record.
